# Order of special linear group $SL_2 (F)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modular-forms

In ex. 1.2.3 on p.21 of Diamond's *A first course in modular forms*, I was trying to show that $$|SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z})|=N^3 \prod_{p|N}(1-1/p^2).$$

First of all, I knew that If $F$ is a field with $q$ elements, then $|GL_2(F)|=(q^2-1)(q^2-q)$. If we consider the surjective homomorphism $\det : GL_2(F) \rightarrow F^*$ with kernel $SL_2(F)$, then we have $|SL_2(F)|=(q^2-1)(q^2-q)/(q-1)=q(q^2-1)=q^3-q$. Therefore if we replace $F$ by $\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z}$, we get $|SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z})|= N^3-N$, but thats' not agree with the book, so what's wrong with me...?
In fact, in the part (a) of the problem, it asks us show $|SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^e \mathbb{Z})|=p^{3e}(1-1/p^2)$ for $p$ prime (that's already doesn't agree with my conclusion...), and uses chinese remainder theorem to conclude.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}$ is a field if and only if $e=1$

Comment: oh my god.... I got it... I am such a moron.....

Comment: @MTurgeon Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

Your computation only works when $\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, which of course happens if and only if $e=1$.

Answer (score 0):

These questions are answered by points 1 and 2 of an earlier answer.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/341435/14120