# What is the order of the group $SL_n(\mathbb Z_l) $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

If $l$ is a prime number $p$, then I know how to compute the order of $SL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$. (By using row vectors linearly independent choices)
But what would be the order if $l$ is any natural number(may not be a prime).

Comment: For $n=2$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720370/order-of-sl-2-mathbbz-n-mathbbz). Now generalize, using the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Actually, the answer is given there already. One can also start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169105/the-cardinality-of-textgln-mathbbz-m-mathbbz?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_totient_function#Order_of_matrix_groups

Comment: $|GL_n(\Bbb{Z}/(l))|=\prod_{p^k\|l} |GL_n(\Bbb{Z}/(p^k))|=\prod_{p^k\|l} p^{n(k-1)} |GL_n(\Bbb{Z}/(p))|$ and $|GL_n(\Bbb{Z}/(l))|=\phi(l) |SL_n(\Bbb{Z}/(l))|$