# Find the cardinality of the group $GL(2, \mathbb{Z/p^{n}Z}) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, finite-groups

Find the cardinality of the group $GL(2, \mathbb{Z/p^{n}Z}) $ for each prime $p$ and positive integer $n$ .

What I know : Clearly if $n=1$ then cardinality of $GL(2, \mathbb{Z/pZ}) $is number of ordered bases of a two dimensional vector space over the field $ \mathbb{Z/pZ}$ i.e. $(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$.
Also a square matrix $A$ is invertible over the ring  $\mathbb {Z/p^{n}Z}$ when $det(A)$ is not a multiple of $p$.Please help!

Comment: If you are given the first column, do you see what the condition is on the second column for the determinant not to be divisible by $p$?

Comment: The kernel of the natural projection onto ${\rm GL}(2,p)$ consists of matrices of the form $I_2 + pM$, where $M$ is any $2 \times 2$ matrix over ${\mathbb Z}/p^n{\mathbb Z}$. That allows you to compute the order of the kernel and hence of the whole group.

Comment: Related (but one answer there is wrong): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169105 ; see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341033.