# Finding the order of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $G = GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})$. Find $|G|$.

$G$ is the group of invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$. In this case, I know invertibility is equivalent to the condition that the determinant of the chosen matrix is a unit of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$. Now, $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})^{\times} = \{\bar{a} : (a, p^2) = 1 \}.$ So, we know $a$ cannot be a multiple of $p$. My idea is to count the number of elements that *do* give a determinant a multiple of $p$, and then subtract this quantity from the total number of possible matrices, $p^8$. So we are looking for solutions of the equation $ad-bc \equiv 0(mod p),$ or $ad \equiv bc (mod p)$. I know for the field case, a common trick is to fix the first column and find conditions on the second column that give the desired result.

So fix $a = a_0$ and $c = c_0$ and consider $a_0d \equiv bc_0 (mod p).$ A class of solutions that jumps out at me is $b \equiv a_0 (mod p)$ and $d \equiv c_0 (mod p).$ But are these the only solutions? Is this even the right way to go about this problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `$x\equiv y\pmod{p}$` for $x\equiv y\pmod{p}$.

Comment: $|GL_2(\Bbb{F}_p)|= (p^2-1)(p^2-p)$ (choose a non-zero vector then another one not in the subgroup it generates) and $GL_2(\Bbb{Z}/(p^2))\to GL_2(\Bbb{F}_p)$ is surjective with kernel the matrices $\equiv I\bmod p$ so the kernel has $p^4$ elements.

Comment: Hint: [1] Reduce all the entries $\pmod p$ and you get a matrix in $M_2(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$. [2] Prove that the reduced matrix $\pmod p$ is invertible if and only if the original matrix is invertible. [3] How many elements are there in $GL_2(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$? [4] "Lift" that number to the number of invertible matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb Z/p^2\mathbb Z)$

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341033/how-to-calculate-operatorname-sl-2-mathbb-z-n-mathbb-z) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064295/find-the-cardinality-of-the-group-gl2-mathbbz-pnz).